# How to copy String array content into String array index in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to assign `get1` into `mealplan[complete][0][1]` but when I display it just displays `[null, null, null, null, null]`. Sample content of String fruits[][] and Mdtfruit[][] is `{"Apple","35","1","pc","40"}`

```
    String[][][][] mealplan = new String[7][6][4][5];
    int complete=0;
    boolean finished=false;

    while(!finished)
    {
         String[] get1=new String[4];
         int num=rand.nextInt(29);
         get1=fruits[num];
         int t = Integer.parseInt(get1[1]);
         get1[1]=String.valueOf(t*Integer.parseInt(Mdtfruit[2]));
         int t2 = Integer.parseInt(get1[2]);
         get1[2]=String.valueOf(t2*Integer.parseInt(Mdtfruit[2]));
         int t3 = Integer.parseInt(get1[4]);
         get1[4]=String.valueOf(t3*Integer.parseInt(Mdtfruit[2]));
         mealplan[complete][0][1]=get1;

         complete+=1;
         if(complete==6)
             finished=true;
    }
```

Comment: A 4D array is way too complicated for someone who has not yet grasped that array indexes start at 0...

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing starts with 0, not 1. Change get1[1] to get1[0] doing same for rest. You declared `mealplan` as an array with 4 dimensions, how can you access it with 3 dimensions?

Comment: I am aware of array indexing. I am not assigning get[1]. The name of the String is get1. And I am trying to assign get1 to the 3rd dimension that's why i'm accessing with 3

Comment: You declared get1 to hold 4 string. You started indexing from 1 till 4. You can't access `get1[4]` because the size is 4, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

your        get1=fruits[num];
is throwing compilation error because get1 is of array of string and you are trying to assign String.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that fruits and mdtfruit are 2d arrays. now i edited it

Comment: Mdtfruit[2] is throwing error because it is 2D array .